# Getting TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tags' and 'export_dir'"

Tags: api, object, detection

I am executing the below code:

CODE:

"model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)"

Comment: I am using the Git hub repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Comment: Using Tensorflow 1.x

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please `edit` your question to include additional detail instead of adding detail using comments.